# Solr Query for item in Group

Tags: solr

Here is a sample document structure I have in Solr:

```
{'id': '1', group:'1', type='veggie', 'data':'potato'},
{'id': '2', group:'1', type='fruit', 'data':'tomato'},
{'id': '3', group:'2', type='fruit','data':'123'},
{'id': '4', group:'3',  type='veggie', 'data':'pot123ato'},
```

I can group the results by group field, however I also want to do queries based on groups, to retrieve groups.

For example, I want to run a query for any group that has both a fruit and a veggie item as type. Any way to do that with this document structure?

Comment: did you try out anything?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You cant directly until you are ready to modify your schema.

TO do this without modifying schema, you have to write custom post filter.

Check out this excellent [post](http://qaware.blogspot.in/2014/11/how-to-write-postfilter-for-solr-49.html) on how to write it. You would have to implement a custom post filter and pass some keys like what fields to filter on to achieve your goal.